# Circular and Reciprocal Functions

Tags: trigonometry

How do you show the following?

$sec(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x) = -csc(x)$

I get to,

$\frac{1}{cos(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x)} = -csc(x)$

and then using the 'CAST' quadrant rule,

$\frac{1}{cos(x)} = -csc(x)$

This is where I get stuck

Comment: Try making a unit circle and labelling the coordinates of point on it at $x=270^{\circ}=\frac{3\pi}2$ for an intuitive approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your last is not correct-it asserts $\frac 1{\cos(x)}=\frac 1{\sin(x)}$.  I don't know the CAST rule, but you can just expand $\cos (\frac {3\pi}2-x)=\cos(\frac {3\pi}2)\cos (x) + \sin (\frac {3\pi}2)\sin (x)=-\sin (x)$ to get where you need.